# Using a (Rich)TextBox as a window onto a larger buffer

Tags: c#, text, text-editor

I feel like I'm missing an obvious point here, but let's say I'm working on a text editor, and I'd like to store a file's (partial?) contents as a text buffer.  My text buffer is some specialized data structure for holding lots of text, not just a simple string or StringBuilder.  I'd also like to expose the text to the user, probably through a standard text box or rich text box.

What is the best means of doing this?

Would I copy a segment out of the buffer into the textbox, then adjust everything manually and copy changes back?  Would I copy the entire buffer as a string into the textbox?  If I was only loading part of a file into the buffer (to handle very large files) would I have to set up a second translation layer from buffer to file?  Do I need an entirely different control from the built in textboxes to accomplish this?

EDIT: I'd also accept suggestions for 3rd-party text controls that would work well.  My main block here is not wanting to build/learn/import the entirety of (for example) GTK or QT just to get a decent text editor control.

Comment: You can't make this work well with RTB, the scrollbar will be off badly.  I don't suppose advise to not try to edit megabytes of text is helpful, you really do need to use a real text editor control.

Comment: Haha, if I was writing it just for kicks I'd not worry about opening multi-megabyte text files, since it isn't really something I do much, but I want to write this more generally and I couldn't be sure what some crazy user might attempt to open with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the ebook referenced from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215639/sharpdevelop-ebook), the sharpdevelop guys go into some detail on how to construct a text editor.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I was looking at the sharpdevelop code and figured that would be the best place to go for getting a good C# native text control.  Nice to have confirmation.

Comment: It seems like the #dev guys made some major changes from 3 to 4.  Do they list anywhere the reasons for going from Gap Buffers to Ropes and from their textarea control to WPF?

Comment: Not that I know of unfortunately.  I've not looked at sharpdevelop for a number of years.

Answer (score 1):

I use a RichTextBox in [logview4net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/logview4net/) as a window on whatever data I'm looking at. 
It is only forward scrolling and I can't really say I like it.

I think you're better off looking for some other editor control.

Comment: For a forward only control, I can see how it would work ok.  Thank you for the push in a different direction.  I was afraid that the RTB would be too difficult to use for serious text editing.